# How to determine a string is english or arabic?

Tags: java

Is there a way to determine a string is English or Arabic?

Comment: From the perspective of the world today, "1234" is both I think?

Comment: @Nishant, does Arabic use regular numbers or Rumi?

Comment: Do you mean whether it contains english or arabic text, or whether is it encoded that way ? The second case should be quite easy, as the characters are not in the same Unicode range (see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet).

Comment: You can't do this in a deterministic way. All information must tell what it is. That is the reason for [content-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), encoding, etc. But you may guess.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is a simple logic that I just tried:

```
  public static boolean isProbablyArabic(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length();) {
        int c = s.codePointAt(i);
        if (c >= 0x0600 && c <= 0x06E0)
            return true;
        i += Character.charCount(c);            
    }
    return false;
  }
```

It declares the text as arabic if and only if an arabic unicode code point is found in the text. You can enhance this logic to be more suitable for your needs.

The range 0600 - 06E0 is the code point range of Arabic characters and symbols (See [Unicode tables](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html))

Comment: You may also want to check the _other_ Arabic ranges - see the link in my answer.

Comment: This method is very inefficient for large strings as it calculates the length of string in each iteration. Character.codePointCount(s, 0, s.length()) should be first assigned to a variable so that it doesn't call this function in each iteration.

Comment: @jazib: Actually the bigger problem was the iteration over the code points, which was incorrect. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 13):

Java in itself supports various language checks by unicode, Arabic is also supported. Much simpler and smallest way to do the same is by UnicodeBlock

```
public static boolean textContainsArabic(String text) {
    for (char charac : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(charac) == Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not compilable in my case unless i replace Character.UnicodeBlock.Ar with Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC, also kindly notice that your method name is wrong isTextContainsHindi it should be isTextContainsArabic  @Guarav Tyagi

Comment: @Jeeva For check of English, English characters tend to be in these 4 Unicode blocks: BASIC_LATIN, LATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT, LATIN_EXTENDED_A, GENERAL_PUNCTUATION

Answer (score 9):

A minor change to cover all arabic characters and symbols range

```
private boolean isArabic(String text){
        String textWithoutSpace = text.trim().replaceAll(" ",""); //to ignore whitepace
        for (int i = 0; i < textWithoutSpace.length();) {
            int c = textWithoutSpace.codePointAt(i);
          //range of arabic chars/symbols is from 0x0600 to 0x06ff
            //the arabic letter 'لا' is special case having the range from 0xFE70 to 0xFEFF
            if (c >= 0x0600 && c <=0x06FF || (c >= 0xFE70 && c<=0xFEFF)) 
                i += Character.charCount(c);   
            else                
                return false;

        } 
        return true;
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can usually tell by the code points within the string itself. Arabic occupies [certain blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) in the Unicode code space.

It's a fairly safe bet that, if a substantial proportion of the characters exist in those blocks (such as `بلدي الحوامات مليء الثعابينة`), it's Arabic text.

Comment: You should provide a very short Java demo of your idea. Otherwise, I think this is the best way to go in this case (english vs arabic).

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15107721/3760297) is somewhat correct. But when we combine Farsi and English letters it returns **TRUE**!, which is not true.
Here I modified the same method so that it works well

```
 public static boolean isProbablyArabic(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length();) {
        int c = s.codePointAt(i);
        if (!(c >= 0x0600 && c <= 0x06E0))
            return false;
        i += Character.charCount(c);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use *N-gram-based text categorization* (google for that phrase) but it is not a fail-proof technique, and it may require a not too short string.

You might also decide that a string with only ASCII letters is not Arabic.

Comment: It also needs a considerable amount of training data (not to mention training time).

Answer (score 0):

English characters tend to be in these 4 Unicode blocks:

- BASIC_LATIN
- LATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT
- LATIN_EXTENDED_A
- GENERAL_PUNCTUATION

  ```
  public static boolean isEnglish(String text) {

   boolean onlyEnglish = false;

   for (char character : text.toCharArray()) {

      if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(character) == Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN
              || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(character) == Character.UnicodeBlock.LATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT
              || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(character) == Character.UnicodeBlock.LATIN_EXTENDED_A
              || Character.UnicodeBlock.of(character) == Character.UnicodeBlock.GENERAL_PUNCTUATION) {

          onlyEnglish = true;
      } else {

          onlyEnglish = false;
      }
   }

    return onlyEnglish;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just an adaptation of existing answer to Kotlin:

```
fun String.textContainsArabic(): Boolean =
    any { Character.UnicodeBlock.of(it) == Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with my code and it works fine.
Using codePointAt which is a method that returns the Unicode value of the character at the specified index in a string.

```
  public static boolean isItArabic(String someText)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<someText.length(); i++)
    {
        int point = someText.codePointAt(i);
        if(!(point >= 1536 && point <= 1791)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
internal static bool ContainsArabicLetters(string text)

{

foreach (char character in text.ToCharArray())
{
    if (character >= 0x600 && character <= 0x6ff)
        return true;
    if (character >= 0x750 && character <= 0x77f)
        return true;
    if (character >= 0xfb50 && character <= 0xfc3f)
        return true;
    if (character >= 0xfe70 && character <= 0xfefc)
        return true;
}
return false;
}
```