# A query that select foreign language and execlude arabic

Tags: oracle

I have a column **COL1** that contain different languages english ,arabic

```
  col  col1
  __  __
  1  information
  2  معلومات
```

I am searching for a query to get me only the arabic character

```
 col  col1
  __  __
  2  معلومات
```

I found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932230/oracle-sql-query-that-returns-rows-with-only-numeric-values) that use function REGEXP_LIKE that get only digits, is there a way that I can get the arabic ?

### edit

```
I did this 
   and o.col1 not like ('%A%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%B%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%C%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%D%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%E%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%F%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%G%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%H%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%I%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%J%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%K%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%L%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%M%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%N%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%O%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%P%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%Q%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%R%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%S%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%T%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%U%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%V%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%W%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%X%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%Y%')
   and o.col1 not like ('%Z%')
```

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107313/how-to-determine-a-string-is-english-or-arabic and create a procedure to call the method there within your SGBD :)

Answer (score 1):

REGEXP_LIKE syntax allows searching for characters within a range like `[A-Z]`. Inspired by the link given in the comment by @mounaim, it is possible to let REGEXP_LIKE search for the Unicode range 0600-06FF with this REGEXP_LIKE syntax:

```
select *
  from tab
 where regexp_like(col1, UNISTR('[\0600-\06FF]'))
```

If you need to search for more than the basic Arabic Unicode range ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Unicode ), it can be expanded like:

```
select *
  from tab
 where regexp_like(col1, UNISTR('[\0600-\06FF]|[\0750-\077F]|[\08A0-\08FF]|[\FB50-\FDFF]|[\FE70-\FEFF]'))
```

The `|` here is the REGEXP *OR* operator so that will search for a character in the first range *OR* the second range *OR* etc...

The 5-hex-digit Unicode ranges I have no idea how to search for, but I hazard the guess that they are very rarely used ;-)